# Google FCM Field "data" must be a JSON array

Tags: php, android, json, codeigniter, push-notification

I am trying to send Google FireBase Push notification on Android Device. Following My code

```
function send_android_notification($deviceToken="",$message="",$input_data=array())
  {       
    $apiKey =  'XXXXXXXXXX';
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
            //'to'  => $deviceToken,
            'registration_ids' => array($deviceToken),
            'notification'=> array( "body" => $message,"title"=>"ABCD","icon"=>""),
            'data' => $input_data
            );
    $headers = array( 
              'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
              'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    // Execute post
    $result1 = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result1;
    curl_close($ch);
  }
```

But It give me Following Error while I am sending Push Notification

**Field "data" must be a JSON array: []**

Comment: Try this json_encode($fields , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)

Comment: Thank you @Scaffold You saved my Time. Done Perfect

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your array to json

```html
json_encode($input_data)
```